# adding values entered by user in a separate text area

Tags: javascript, html

I need to display an HTML form where user enters a value in a field. A textarea is displayed in the same form. Once user inputs text into the text field and clicks on submit, the values submitted should be appended and displayed in the textarea box. Something like:

field 1: some text box

field 2: text box

Submit button

field 3: When i click submit, display the texts entered in field 1 and field 2 together in this textarea.

Any ideas on this will be very helpfull.

Comment: When the user hits the submit button, the page redirects, so it doesn't matter what happens next. If you can't figure out how to put the value from one element into another, you have a lot of learning ahead to figure out ajax calls before you can solve your problem.

Comment: What server language are you using to process the request? You have to return it to the HTML so that it can print it

Comment: do you want to show a confirmation display of field 2 before submission or like a receipt after the form sends?

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to do like this, try this one...

```
<input type="text" id="txt1"/>
<input type="text" id="txt2"/>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="btn1"/> 
<textarea id="txt3">hello</textarea>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        txt1=$("#txt1").val();
        txt2=$("#txt2").val();
        //alert(txt1+txt2;
        $("#txt3").val(txt1+txt2);
    });
});
```

click on this for live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vwckksL6/1/

thank you